# Extjs Confirm Password

Tags: validation, passwords, extjs, confirm

I have two password fields and am trying to confirm they are the same before allowing the post to happen.  Here is my code, it's returning "Passwords do not match!" every time no matter what.  When I do an `alert(pass1)` after my `var pass1 = ...` line, it gives me `undefined`.  I've also tried `var pass1 = formPanel.findField("txt_newPIN").getValue()` and it returns the same thing.  Here's the code:

```
    {
    fieldLabel:"PIN/Password",
    actionText:"Edit",
    fieldValue:"****",
    dialog:new MyAccount.DialogBox({
        id:"win_editPIN",
        name:"editPIN",
        headerContent:"Edit Password:",
        updateURL:"/uiapi/myaccount/setAccountPIN",
        items:[{
            id:"txt_currentPIN",
            name: "currentPIN",
            fieldLabel: "Current Password",
            validationEvent:"blur",
            allowBlank: false,
            maxLength:20,
            inputType:"password"
        },{
            id:"txt_newPIN",
            name: "newPIN",
            fieldLabel: "New Password",
            vtype:"confirmPassword",
            validationEvent:"blur",
            allowBlank: false,
            maxLength:20,
            inputType:"password"
        },{
            id:"txt_confirmPIN",
            fieldLabel: "Confirm Password",
            vtype:"confirmPassword",
            validationEvent:"blur",
            initialPin:"txt_newPIN",
            allowBlank: false,
            maxLength:20,
            inputType:"password"
        }], 


 validateForm:function() {
     var formPanel = Ext.getCmp("win_editPIN").formPanel.getForm();
         // Save the fields we are going to insert values into
         var pass1 = formPanel.findField("txt_newPIN");
     var pass2 = formPanel.findField("txt_confirmPIN");

         if (pass1 != pass2)
             return {success:false,  errorMessage:"Passwords do not match!"}
         }

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass field name instead of field id when use findField() method.

```
var pass1 = formPanel.findField("newPIN");
```

or simply just get its value directly

```
var pass1 = Ext.getCmp('txt_newPIN').getValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Nghia, your answer got me halfway there, allowing me to select the fields.  The rest was making a custom `validator` option, here is the code, just showing the last item for brevity.

```
     {
            id:"txt_confirmPIN",
            name: "newPIN_confirm",
            fieldLabel: "Confirm Password",
            validationEvent:"blur",
            initialPin:"txt_newPIN",
            allowBlank: false,
            maxLength:20,
            inputType:"password",
            // This custom validator option expects a return value of boolean true if it
            // validates, and a string with an error message if it doesn't
            validator: function() {
                   var formPanel = Ext.getCmp("win_editPIN").formPanel.getForm();
                   // Save the fields we are going to insert values into
                   var pass1 = Ext.getCmp('txt_newPIN').getValue();
                   var pass2 = Ext.getCmp('txt_confirmPIN').getValue();
                   console.log("pass 1 = " + pass1 + "--pass 2 = " + pass2);

                    if (pass1 == pass2)
                        return true;

                    else 
                        return "Passwords do not match!";
            }
        }
```

This validator option expects a return value of true if it validates, and a string with an error message if it doesn't.